# What is the correct permission for Android "content://gmail-ls/conversations/xxxxx@gmail.com"

Tags: android, permissions, gmail

I'm trying to read my gmail in Android like:

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/conversations/xxxxx@gmail.com"), null,   null, null, null);

String[] columns = cur.getColumnNames();
```

and get a permission exception:
Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gm.provider.MailProvider from ProcessRecord{416bc448 3111:com.t2.bigbrother/10070} (pid=3111, uid=10070) requires com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL or com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL

I've tried to add the permission but still get the exception. I'm on Ice Cream Sanwitch (Nexus)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Permission error java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial on 3.x Android devices while getting email attachment name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441866/getting-permission-error-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-on-3-x-a)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just can't do this anymore

See:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/XD0C4sw9K7U/LpNXxFNnfgc%5B1-25%5D

Answer (score 0):

com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL will be the correct permission in this case.